# Replacing a letter with a space

Tags: python

I am pretty much finished with this code but I can't get the letter "t" -- lower case and upper case -- to be replaced by a space. Tho format of my code should be the same but I just need help replacing the "t" with a space. For example, "The book on the table thttg" should look like " he book on  he  able  h  g." So, pretty much the "t" should be hidden.

```
def remoeT(aStr):
    userInput = ""
    while True:
        string = raw_input("Enter a word/sentence you want to process:")
        if string == "Quit":
            return userInput

        userInput = userInput + string
        if aStr != False:
            while "t" in userInput:
                index = userInput.find("t")
                userInput = userInput[:index] + userInput[index+1:]
        while "T" in userInput:
            index = userInput.find("T")
            userInput = userInput[:index] + userInput[index+1:]
```

Comment: Use [`str.replace`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) method instead of that slice stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To replace all occurrences of `t` and `T` with a space in the string `input`, use the following:

```
input = input.replace('t', ' ').replace('T', ' ')
```

Or with regular expressions:

```
import re
input = re.sub('[tT]', ' ', input)
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning `string.replace` before getting out the big guns (regex).

Comment: Hm, where do I place input = input.replace('t', ' ').replace('T', ' ') accordingly into my code for it to work?

Comment: @queensmatin `userInput = userInput.replace('t', ' ').replace('T', ' ')`, just before `if aStr != False:` (and then you don't need any of the other logic for replacing `t` characters)

Comment: Actually, it did not work. I need it to be the same format. The only thing I need is to replace both lower case and capital with a space

Answer (score 4):

Why not simply use the [replace](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=replace#str.replace) function?

```
s = 'The book on the table thttg it Tops! Truely'
s.replace('t', ' ').replace('T', ' ')
```

yields:

```
' he book on  he  able  h  g i   ops!  ruely'
```

maybe not as nice as using a regular expression, but functional.

However, this seems substantially faster than the regular expression approach (thanks to @JoranBeasley motivating the benchmarking):

```
timeit -n 100000 re.sub('[tT]', ' ', s)
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.76 us per loop

timeit -n 100000 s.replace('t', ' ').replace('T', ' ')
100000 loops, best of 3: 546 ns per loop
```

Comment: just out of curiousity... this would take longer than the re.sub example since it needs to go through teh string 2x?

Comment: @JoranBeasley interesting question, not sure. Would have to benchmark it to find out. (I may try, if I do, I'll post the results)

Comment: The regular expression performance could be improved by compiling the RE beforehand. But my guess is that it's still gonna be slower than `str.replace`.

Comment: @LukasGraf That would be my guess too.

Answer (score 3):

Use a regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> st = "this is a sample input with a capital T too."
>>> re.sub('[tT]', ' ', st)
' his is a sample inpu  wi h a capi al    oo.'
```

Also, don't name a variable "string"; there's a "string" class that will hide.

Comment: I cant import anything. It musted be either the function replace or indexed

Comment: Then use the string.replace method as referenced in other answers. Also, accept an answer, please.